# Does a IEnumerable store objects after use

Tags: c#, performance, ienumerable

If I have a very large `IEnumerable` collection, in the order of millions of objects, that would be too large to load all at once. The collections is returned via a yield method:

```
 private static IEnumerable<MyData> ExtractModelsFromDb()
    {
        using (DbDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
        {
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                Load MyData
                yield return MyData;
            }
            reader.Close();
        }
    }
```

This Data is consumed in a single `Foreach` loop:

```
public void RunStuff()
    {
        var myCollection = ExtractModelsFromDb();

        foreach (var data in myCollection)
        {
           //DO STUFF 
        }
    }
```

I know that the collection under the `IEnumerable` is getting loaded one object at a time, but are the objects getting removed once they have been used in the `ForEach` or do they remain in the collection until the `ForEach` is complete.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It depends on the implementation. It is *not* against the specification for an `IEnumerable` to store the values in the sequence that it represents. In fact, a `List<T>` is an `IEnumerable<T>` that does exactly that!

Now, for the `IEnumerable` that *you* have, it will *not* store the objects after it returns them. `DbDataReader`s merely stream the results to you, and `yield return`ing them will not store them. So, your `foreach` is just streaming through the result set from `DbDataReader`, and no one is storing them as you [go gently down the stream](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Row,_Row,_Row_Your_Boat).